# ¿Por qué un while do ... done < "$nombre" me da error de sintaxis?

Tags: bash, while, shell-script

Tengo este codigo y me da un error de sintaxis en la linea fina. Me dice que es incorrecta la sintaxis `done < "$nombre"`.

Esto supongo que sera porque nombre es una variable pero no sé cómo arreglarlo para que el `while` me lea de una variable.

Creo que hay que poner `done <<< "$nombre"` pero no se la diferencia entre `done < "$nombre"`, `done < < "$nombre` y
`done <<< "$nombre"`

```
#!/bin/bash

nombre=$(sudo lastb | awk '{print $1,$4,$5}' | sort | uniq -c | tr -s ' ')

while read -r num user dia mes
do
    echo "$num , $user, $dia ,$mes "
done < "$nombre"
```

Comment: Hola Diego. ¿que esperas que haga la instrucción  done < "$nombre"?

Answer (score 3):

En la última línea, en:

```
done < "$nombre"
```

En lugar de utilizar el token `<`, utiliza un here-string `<<<`, es decir:

```
done <<< "$nombre"
```

Esto es porque el operador `<` opera sobre nombres de archivos, y lo que contenga la cadena "$nombre", parece que no está muy relacionada con un nombre de archivo.

Por otro lado, el operador `<<<` le indica a la shell que la cadena de texto que esté a la derecha le será introducida al *sdtin* al comando de la izquierda, que en tu caso es bucle `while`. Esto se conoce como *here-string*.

Para terminar, al mecanismo `<<`, se le llama *here-document*. En este caso, la cadena que esté a la derecha de dicho operador será leído como el final del documento; mientras tanto, todo el texto que difiera de esa cadena será introducida al stdin del comando a la izquierda. Ejemplo:

```
$ cat - << __este_es_el_separador__
Esto se va a imprimir
También este comando: $(date)
Al final ponemos la cadena que definimos como indicador
del fin del documento.
__este_es_el_separador__

Esto se va a imprimir
También este comando: Sat Aug 29 11:44:06 CDT 2020
Al final ponemos la cadena que definimos como indicador
del fin del documento.
```

Esto lo puedes leer en el manual de Bash, en `bash(1)`, en la sección de **REDIRECTION**.

La siguiente publicación en SO también tiene información que te puede aclarar algunos asuntos:

- [¿Por qué EOF no expande una variable?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/212874/por-qu%C3%A9-eof-no-expande-una-variable/212879#212879)

Comment: buena y exhaustiva respuesta. También existe `< <(comando)`

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la sintaxis del while con lanredireccion de entrada es correcta. El único detalle es que en `nombre` debes estar indicando el nombre de un archivo que vas a leer..... y pareciera que en `nombre` no tienes eso, sino algo más complejo. Quieres pasar el output de la primera parte al while? Por qué no los conectas con un pipe?

```
sudo blah | mas bla | bla bla | while read -r bum usar día mes
do
    hacer algo
done
```